# Bootstrap 4 In-Line Navbar Form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this navbar built with Bootstrap 4.

I'm trying to add the search bar inline and have added the 'form-inline' class to the search form but the search button is still under the text box.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-secondary fixed-top">
    
    <!-- LOGO on left -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/DHI Logo Navbar.svg" alt="Diversified" style="width:70px;">
    </a>

    <!-- Toggler/Collapsible Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navbar Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="index.php" class="nav-link">PDF Generator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="contacts.php" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="inspectionLog.php" class="nav-link">Inspection Log</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline" action="inspectionLog.php">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    

</nav>
```

I'm trying to get the logo on the left, links in the middle (which they are) and the search bar on the right in-line.

Do you guys see any mistakes that might stop the in-line search bar?

Answer (score 0):

The term "in-line" in CSS means that it behaves like normal text would, so when the screen size is smaller, the elements wrap around, meaning your button goes below the input.

What you need is, to somehow group them together.
The easiest fix would be to use `style="display: flex;"` on the `form` tag, and remove the class.

But, you could use a bootstrap class if you wish to: `class="d-inline-flex"`

Having them be displayed as a flexbox tells the elements to stick to one line, and just wrap the whole thing when the screen gets smaller.

EDIT to your edit

Remove the `bg-secondary` class from the `<nav>` and it should work fine. Also remove the `;` after the curly brackets, you don't need that.

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #34495E;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bg-secondary, try a new one like bg-custom

```
<style>
    .bg-custom {
        background-color: #66ACF3;
    };
</style>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-custom fixed-top">

    <!-- LOGO on left -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/DHI Logo Navbar.svg" alt="Diversified" style="width:70px;">
    </a>

    <!-- Toggler/Collapsible Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navbar Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="index.php" class="nav-link">PDF Generator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="contacts.php" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="inspectionLog.php" class="nav-link">Inspection Log</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```